# "transforms.Reroute.topic.regex" and "table.include.list" in property Json of Debezium SQL connector

Tags: sql, debezium, reroute

``As per below property files, expected behavior is to route events from "table.include.list": "dbo.idm_assets,dbo.idm_datapoints" to queue - debezium_assets and from "table.include.list": "dbo.idm_workorder,dbo.idm_activity" to queue - debezium_events.`

```
`{
  "name": "sql-server-kafkacdc-idm-connection",
  "config": {
    "snapshot.mode": "initial_schema_only",
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
    "database.hostname": "localhost",
    "database.port": "1433",
    "database.user": "cdc_idm_owner",
    "database.password": "cdcIdm@2022",
    "database.dbname": "kafkacdc",
    "database.server.name": "kafkacdc",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
    "tombstones.on.delete": false,
    "table.include.list": "dbo.idm_assets,dbo.idm_datapoints",
    "transforms": "Reroute",
    "transforms.Reroute.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
    "transforms.Reroute.topic.regex": "(.*)",
    "transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement": "debezium_assets",
    "database.history":"io.debezium.relational.history.MemoryDatabaseHistory" 
  }
}`
```

```
{
  "name": "sql-server-kafkacdc-idm-all-001",
  "config": {
    "snapshot.mode": "initial_schema_only",
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
    "database.hostname": "localhost",
    "database.port": "1433",
    "database.user": "cdc_idm_owner",
    "database.password": "cdcIdm@2022",
    "database.dbname": "kafkacdc",
    "database.server.name": "kafkacdc",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
    "tombstones.on.delete": false,
    "table.include.list": "dbo.idm_workorder,dbo.idm_activity",
    "transforms": "Reroute",
    "transforms.Reroute.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
    "transforms.Reroute.topic.regex": "(.*)",
    "transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement": "debezium_events",
    "database.history":"io.debezium.relational.history.MemoryDatabaseHistory" 
  }
}
```

But currently, events are being sent to both the queues even if we trigger an event from table of another property file which isn't expected.

Observation : We have deleted one of the connectors(Assets) and tried to reproduce the issue. Triggered an event from Assets table and could see it in Events queue which is not expected.

Please find the current and expected behaviors:

[Current Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y815k.png)
[Expected Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neHoD.png)`